# JavaFX/CSS: Changing text color of ComboBox's selected item

Tags: java, css, javafx, combobox, scenebuilder

I'm using a custom JavaFX library called JFoenix that overhauls some JavaFX components with Google's Material Design.  The problem I'm specifically running into is changing the text color of a ComboBox of Strings' selected item after it has been selected.  [This is my before screen, with the item in question circled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAMnO.jpg)

The text turns from gray to black when I select an item from the ComboBox ([see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyQ74.png)).  I want the text from the selected item to be the same color as the rest of the labels.  Adding a `-fx-text-fill` or `-fx-text-inner-color` in Scene Builder doesn't work.

The only possible solution I've found is making the ComboBox editable and setting the color through its Editor after the user selects an option:

```
@FXML
private void handleComboBoxFormat() {
     this.mpaaBox.getEditor().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #eceff1;" + "-fx-background-color: #445566");
}
```

I don't like this solution because I don't want the ComboBox to be editable, and it just feels messy.  Is there any other way to edit the text color?  Thanks!

Comment: I think they have there own set of css fields prefixed as `-jfx-`. Take a look at their website (i find it very hard to use the website, as the navigation covers the actual content).

Comment: You're right, but there's only these three: `-jfx-focus-color`, `-jfx-unfocus-color`, and `-jfx-label-float`, none of which address the text.

Comment: Try focus color.

Comment: I have, `-jfx-focus-color` and `-jfx-unfocus-color` affect the text bar, not the actual text.

Answer (score 3):

`-fx-text-fill` isn't defined in combo box.

But reading the [CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) I see the structure:

```
.combo-box > .list-view > .list-cell
```

where `.list-cell` defines `-fx-text-fill` inherited from Labeled.

Comment: Just tried doing that and it didn't work.  I'm not 100% familiar with CSS syntax, but this is what I used: `.combo-box .list-view .list-cell {-fx-text-fill: "#eceff1"; }`

Comment: Update: After messing around with that a little bit, I determined that the `.combo-box .list-view .list-cell` doesn't affect the text of the selected item, just the items in the combobox list.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so after messing with the CSS that @MouseEvent suggested, I figured out the solution.

`.combo-box .list-view .list-cell` affects the items in the ComboBox's list when you open the pop-up.

`.combo-box .list-cell` affects the label of the selected item, which was what I was having trouble accessing.

Answer (score 1):

Much thanks, this helped me alot. I played with it some more, and I was able to achieve this styling.

[image]

Using these entries:

```
/* outer combo-box text */
.combo-box .list-cell {
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}

/* combo-box list view text, not hovered or focused */
.combo-box .list-view .list-cell {
  -fx-text-fill: black;
}

/* combo-box selected text */
.combo-box .list-view .list-cell:focused {
  -fx-background-color : #5F9EA0;  /* Cadet Blue */
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}

/* combo-box hover text */
.combo-box .list-view .list-cell:hover {
  -fx-background-color : #5F9EA0;  /* Cadet Blue */
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```